# View images via Lightbox (or similiar) from a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to view a gallery of images via Lightbox (or something similiar). The only problem is I need to display the image set in the viewer from a hyperlink rather than displaying thumbnails of the image set.

Does anyone know if this is possible; if so could you point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

I've edited this, to hopefully clarify my question.

What I want to do is have one hyperlink that when clicked opens a lightbox (or type of pop up viewer/gallery) that contains multiple images that the user can scroll through.

thanks

Barry

Comment: do you have any specific js library that you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using JQuery, then [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net) is a good lightbox plugin to suite your needs.

With FancyBox what you can use is, inline modal window to display images in a lightbox; when a hyperlink is clicked.

examples tailored for your need are at the bottom of this page:  [Examples of manual call](http://fancybox.net/home)

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks to the other replies for their help also.

Answer (score 2):

Using lightbox, shadowbox or something similar it's no problem to use links without thumbnails.

```
<a rel="lightbox[picturegallery]" href="pic1.jpg" title="Pic1">Pic1</a>
<a rel="lightbox[picturegallery]" href="pic2.jpg" title="Pic2">Pic2</a>
<a rel="lightbox[picturegallery]" href="pic3.jpg" title="Pic3">Pic3</a>
```

Further info and code examples can be found [here](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Answer (score 1):

this could be the direction.

```
$('a').click(function(){
var that = $(this)
var html= that.attr('href') // Read the href of the link and use it as reference for your lightbox.
$('body').append('<div id="shadow"><div id="fancybox"><img src="' + html +'" alt="pic" /></div></div>')
    $('#shadow').click(function(){
        $(this).remove()
    })
return false;
})
```

you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/hRcWN/2/

Comment: Thanks meo - the demo looks good for single images.  But I can't see how this would work for image sets.  i.e multiple images from one link.

Comment: there are more then one possibility, you give them names like Gallery_1pic1.jpg and you just count the nubers up. Or you store your filenames somewhere. you have to be more specific, so i can make you a more specific solution.